# how to draw lines in a quartz context that aren't connected end to end?

Tags: ios, cgcontext, cgpath

I am tracking touches in my view and creating corresponding lines in an associated "canvas"
layer. the points are accumulated into a CGPathRef and stored in an NSArray at touchesDidEnd
time.

at drawLayer time I draw both current path and stored paths as follows:

```
  // draw the current line:
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
    NSLog(@"Canvas drawing path %@", path);

    // draw the stored lines
    for (NSMutableArray *arr in storedPaths) {
        CGMutablePathRef aPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
        // set up the path with the CGPointObjects
        NSLog(@"Canvas drawing stored path");
        BOOL inited = NO;
        for (CGPointObject *thePt in arr) {                    
            if (inited==NO) {
                CGPathMoveToPoint(aPath, NULL, [thePt.x floatValue],  [thePt.y floatValue]);
                //CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, [thePt.x floatValue], [thePt.y floatValue]);
                inited = YES;
            }
            else {
                CGPathAddLineToPoint(aPath, NULL, [thePt.x floatValue], [thePt.y floatValue]); 
                //CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, [thePt.x floatValue], [thePt.y floatValue]); 
            }
        }
        CGContextAddPath(ctx, aPath);
        CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
        // didn't help connected problem
        //CGPathRelease(aPath);
    }
```

This works as expected except it connects the end point of the first line to the start point of the next line, instead of leaving them as non-touching separate lines. Example:
user draws an X but gets X with two of the end points connected.

CGClosePath doesn't look like what I want. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If every even/odd pair is a line, then replace 'inited==NO' with a counter and use 'counter%2 == 0' so that for even numbered points it moves to where you want to be and for odd numbered points it connects the previous point. It may be easier to not use fast enumeration but an old fashioned for loop instead.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < [arr count]; ++i) {
        CGPointObject *thePt = [arr objectAtIndex:i];                    
        if (i%2 == 0)
            CGPathMoveToPoint(aPath, NULL, [thePt.x floatValue],  [thePt.y floatValue]);
        else
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(aPath, NULL, [thePt.x floatValue], [thePt.y floatValue]); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

apple's docs on CGContextAddPath() are amazingly inadequate, but it looks like it is continuing the previous path, rather than adding a new subpath.  so, try constructing a single CGMutablePathRef, filling it with subpaths, and then adding the whole thing to the context and stroking it.

i.e., move the call to CGPathCreateMutable() to before the outer loop, and move the calls to CGContextAddPath() and CGContextStrokePath() to after it.  the rest can stay the same.